# Oscillation inequality in $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be in $C^1(B_1)$ where $B_r$ is the ball centered at the origin of radius r.  Let $\omega(r)$ be the oscillation of $u$ on the boundary of $B_r$ and assume that $\omega$ is increasing.  Prove that
$$
\omega(r)^2\leq \frac{\pi}{\log(1/r)}\int_{B_1}|Du|^2dx
$$

To be honest I am sure where to start with this.  I've looked at the right side (without the constant) and computed for $\epsilon>0$
$$
\int_{B_{1-\epsilon}}|Du|^2\;dx\geq \bigg(\int_{B_{1-\epsilon}}Du\;dx\bigg)^2
=\bigg(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\int_{\partial B_r}Du\;dS\;dr \bigg)^2
=\bigg((1-\epsilon)\int_{\partial B_r}Du\;dS\bigg)^2
$$

But I don't know where to go from here.  For context, this is step 1 of a proof of Harnack's Inequality on $\mathbb{R^2}$  In addition to searching here, I could not find any internet resources with this specific inequality nor a proof of Harnack's using the oscillation of a $C^1$ function.

Comment: What are you integrating over? $\mathrm{d}u$? $\mathrm{d}r$? Your integrals are missing terms.

Comment: I've edited my post to include indicating differentials.  My apologies, in my pde course all the differentials are implied so I've followed the bad habit of the professor of never showing them.  In my short computation the inequality follows from Jensen's, and the first equality is a change to polar coordinates as per Evans PDE text, appendix C3.

Comment: ...I think we are in the same class... anyways check out this link. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432342/continuous-function-with-bounded-oscillation-gilbarg-trudinger-ch-8?rq=1